# What’s the meaning of the verb ”does” in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, verbs

I came across the following sentence

”My family **does** think I’m a little bit addicted to fast food.”

What’s the meaning of the verb ”does” in that sentence? Does it have the same meaning as the sentence below?

”My family thinks I’m a little bit addicted to fast food.”

Comment: It's all about emphatic polarity. In this _do_-support construction, stress is placed on the primary verb to emphasise the positive polarity of the clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do) entry for **do**, you will see an entry for **EMPHASIS**. With this meaning, it is followed by a verb infinitive without **to**. You could, for example say:

> I like your dress - *simple statement*
> I **do** like your dress -*emphatic*

When this meaning is used in speech, you would generally put a lot of emphasis on **do**.

The two sentences you quoted have the same meaning, but the first one (with **do**) is more emphatic. This suggests that "a little bit" may be understatement.